# Transforming a StAX Source in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax, xalan

I have some code like:

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl", null)

Transformer t = tf.newTransformer()
DOMResult result = new DOMResult()
t.transform(new StAXSource(reader), result)
```

Which produces the following error:

> Caught: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Can't transform a Source of type javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource

The reader object is of type `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl`

Comment: So the problem here is that I should be actually using a TransformerFactory of type `org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`. Unfortunately, Eclipse doesn't seem to provide that for me. It's also worth noting analogous code outside Eclipse works as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I was stupidly trying the wrong thing. This fixed it:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
"com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon *[Xml Transformer give me an error when trying to transform a StaxSource into a StreamResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68501399/xml-transformer-give-me-an-error-when-trying-to-transform-a-staxsource-into-a-st)*, while looking to solve the very same issue as you.

The answer provided there seems to be working fine for me, i.e. use:

```
TransformerFactory.newDefaultInstance();
```

Instead of:

```
 XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
```